# Oracle Date Format Mystery - Why is it not an acceptable format?

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I am fairly new to SQL but have still written a few queries that are very similar to the one I am writing now. For whatever reason when I run this query I am returned an 'ORA-01821: date format not recognized' error. I looked this up and looked around here on Stack and other places and I believe my syntax does make sense so I am confused as to why I'm thrown an error.

My query runs based on what day of the month it is. If it is the 1st, it should run for the 15th-last day of the previous month. If it is the 16th, it should run for the 1st-15th of the current month.

This is my code for when it is the first day of the month:

```
select 
case
   when to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm' || '01') then (do a lot of things)
   .
   .
   .
end as FirstReportGroup
where *datetable* between between to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm' || '16') and to_char(last_day(sysdate), 'yyyymmdd');
```

and this is my code for when it is the 16th:

```
select 
case
   when to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm' || '16') then (do a lot of things again)
   .
   .
   .
end as SecondReportGroup
where *datetable* between to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm' || '01') and to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm' || '15')
```

It must be some kind of date formatting syntax error that I'm just not seeing. I would really appreciate some help here and I look forward to figuring this out! Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: sysdate is what data type compared to to_char?  (date to character right?) You need to compare like datatypes to start.

Comment: Oh right, foolish mistake. I just changed sysdate to: to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd') and fixed that problem. Still having trouble seeing my syntax error with the date format though.

Comment: the error is caused by '01' and '16', that is not a valid format for to_char instruction, so, if you want to get the day you should use `to_char(sysdate,'dd')`. This return the day part

Comment: Move the 01 outside the to char it's not a date... so `to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm') | '01'`

Answer (score 1):

Two problems

- compare like data types so date on both or string on both but not date and string
- two to_char works only on a date so you need to `to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm') || '16'` instead as to_char only works on the date, you're concating in a string that's not valid to the to_char function.  so do it after the function.

Comment: I had fixed your first point before you answered but I appreciate your follow up regardless. As for your second point, yes that was the problem. A very tiny issue as usual - thank you for pointing it out! I will test and get back.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away with just having one query by using a case statement to generate the start/end dates in the where clause. Here's an example of the case statements:

```
with dts as (select sysdate dt from dual union all
             select to_date('02/06/2014 15:09:23', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual)     
select dt,
       case when dt - trunc(dt, 'mm') < 16 then add_months(trunc(dt, 'mm'), -1) + 15 -- goes from 16th of previous month; change to 14 if needing from 15th.
            else trunc(dt, 'mm')
       end start_dt,
       case when dt - trunc(dt, 'mm') < 16 then trunc(dt, 'mm') -- goes from 16th of previous month; change to 14 if needing from 15th.
            else trunc(dt, 'mm') + 15
       end end_dt
from   dts;

DT                    START_DT              END_DT               
--------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
29/06/2015 12:50:00   01/06/2015 00:00:00   16/06/2015 00:00:00  
02/06/2014 15:09:23   16/05/2014 00:00:00   01/06/2014 00:00:00
```

Bear in mind that a) DATEs in Oracle have a time element as well and b) you probably don't want to be using between, as that makes the start and end period inclusive (you could get rows appearing in both queries, or maybe even miss rows altogether if you get the end_date wrong and forget about anything after midnight on the day in the end_date!) - instead, you probably want to do something like:

```
and datecol >= <case statement generating start_date>
and datecol < <case statement generating end_date>
```